# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints using Cordova

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I get the following error on my Cordova application in XCode.

```
2016-03-22 19:59:11.063 HelloCordova[280:83910] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x17dce400 h=--& v=--& V:[UIKeyboardAssistantBar:0x17e98840(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17eaf150 V:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x17eaddf0]   (Names: '|':UIKeyboardAssistantBar:0x17e98840 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17eaf190 V:[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x17eaddf0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIKeyboardAssistantBar:0x17e98840 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17dd5430 V:|-(0)-[_UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x17dd51c0]   (Names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x17dd46b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17dd54c0 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x17dd51c0.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x17dd46b0.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17dd56a0 'UIButtonBar.maximumAlignmentSize' _UIButtonBarButton:0x17dd46b0.height == UILayoutGuide:0x17eae800'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17eae8d0 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x17eae800'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(3)-|   (Names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x17eaddf0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17eae870 'UIView-topMargin-guide-constraint' V:|-(10)-[UILayoutGuide:0x17eae800'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']   (Names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x17eaddf0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17dd54c0 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x17dd51c0.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x17dd46b0.bottom>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

It's a brand new Cordova install today with the www folder replaced with an application I built a while back.

Where about would I need to look for more information on this?

Need any further information for debugging?

Thank you!

Comment: are you using any plugin that shows native elements?

Comment: I'm using the inAppBrowser plugin. That would be the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Does the app crash? Or just shows that message? I've seen similar messages but nothing bad happens, I think apple screw up with some of their autolayout constrains

Comment: I reinstalled codova and created a new project annd dont see this anymore.